# WPF IDictionary compile error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this DataTemplate in my Window.Resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Interface">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And I'm getting an error

> All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.

But i have the x:Key attribute so i don't know what is wrong.

**EDIT: This is all the Window.Resources**

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Interface">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
            <!-- 
            Merge in the resource dictionary that is shared between the main window and the overview window.
            -->
            <ResourceDictionary 
                Source="SharedVisualTemplates.xaml"
                />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- UI commands. -->

        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteSelectedNodes" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.CreateNode" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteNode" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteConnection" />            
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.ZoomOut" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.ZoomIn" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.JumpBackToPrevZoom" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.FitContent" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.Fill" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.OneHundredPercent" />

        <!-- 
        This converts from a scale value to a percentage value.
        It is used to convert the value of 'ContentScale' to the percentage zoom level that is displayed in the UI.
        -->
        <con:ScaleToPercentConverter 
            x:Key="scaleToPercentConverter" 
            />


        <!-- 
        Define the visual style for a 'ConnectorItem'.
        -->
        <Style 
            TargetType="{x:Type NetworkUI:ConnectorItem}"
            >
            <!-- 
            Data-binding for the connector hotspot.
            ConnectorItem automatically computes its center points and assings this value
            to the 'Hotspot' property.  This data-binding then 'pushes' the value into the application
            view-model.
            -->
            <Setter 
                Property="Hotspot"
                Value="{Binding Hotspot, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                />

            <!-- The visual template. -->
            <Setter 
                Property="Template"
                >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate 
                        TargetType="{x:Type NetworkUI:ConnectorItem}"
                        >
                        <!-- The visual for the connector. -->
                        <Ellipse
                            Stroke="{StaticResource nodeBorderBrush}"
                            Fill="{StaticResource connectorBackgroundBrush}"
                            />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
<!--Style For MainListBox-->
        <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--<Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="Interfaces" IsExpanded="True">                             
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>-->

        <!-- 
        Template for the button that is used to delete nodes and connections in the graph.
        This button is displayed in an adorner when the user hovers the mouse over a node or connection.
        -->
        <ControlTemplate 
            x:Key="deleteButtonTemplate"
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
            >
            <Grid
                x:Name="grid"
                >
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform
                        ScaleX="1"
                        ScaleY="1"
                        CenterX="10"
                        CenterY="10"
                        />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="shadow"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Fill="Gray"
                    >
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform
                            X="1.5"
                            Y="1.5"
                            />
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>                                                            
                </Ellipse>
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="ellipse"
                    Stroke="Black"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Fill="White"
                    />
                <Image
                    Source="Resources\scissors.png" 
                    Margin="2"
                    />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                
                <EventTrigger
                    RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter"
                    >
                    <!-- 
                    Make the 'delete connection button' larger when the mouse 
                    cursor is hovered over it.
                    -->
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                To="1.3"
                                Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                />
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                To="1.3"
                                Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger
                    RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave"
                    >
                    <!-- 
                    Return the 'delete connection button' to normal size when the mouse
                    cursor is moved away.
                    -->
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                />
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- 
        Data-template for ConectionViewModel.

        Note that the 'Start' and 'End' of the arrow are bound to 'SourceConnectorHotspot' and 'DestConnectorHotspot' in 
        the view-model.

        In this sample a curved arrow represents connections between nodes.
        -->
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:ConnectionViewModel}"
            >
            <!-- The connection is represented by a curved arrow. -->
            <ca:CurvedArrow

                    StrokeThickness="2"
                    Points="{Binding Points}"
                    Fill="{StaticResource connectionBrush}"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource connectionBrush}"
                />
            <!--Fill="{Binding isFlow}"-->
            <!--Stroke="{Binding isFlow}"-->

            <!-- 
            An adorned control is used, to represent the connection. 
            When the user hovers the mouse cursor over the connection, the 
            'delete connection' adorner pops up and allows them to delete the connection.
            -->

        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Define a data-template for the 'NodeViewModel' class. -->    
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}"
            >
                <!-- The margin has been selected so that the selection rect nicely covers the entire node. -->

                <Grid
                    MinWidth="120"
                    Margin="10,6,10,6"
                    SizeChanged="Node_SizeChanged"
                    >

                    <!-- This rectangle is the main visual for the node. -->

                    <Rectangle
                        Stroke="{StaticResource nodeBorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1.3"
                        RadiusX="4"
                        RadiusY="4"
                        Fill="{StaticResource nodeFillBrush}"
                        />

                <!-- 
                    This grid contains the node's connectors.
                    The margin is negative so that the connectors overlap the body of the node and it's selection border.
                    -->
                    <Grid
                        Margin="-6,4,-6,4"
                        >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <!-- spacer -->
                            <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- The name of the node. -->                
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            />


                    <!-- Displays the node's input connectors. -->                
                        <ItemsControl
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding InputConnectors}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource inputConnectorTemplate}"
                            Focusable="False"
                            />

                        <!-- Displays the node's output connectors. -->
                        <ItemsControl
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding OutputConnectors}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource outputConnectorTemplate}"
                            Focusable="False"
                            />



                    <ListBox Name="lbInterfaces"  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Interfaces}" ItemTemplate="InterfacesDataTemplate" >

                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    </ListBox>

                    <ListBox Name="lbEnums"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding Enums}">
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Enums"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <ListBox Name="lbStructs"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding Structs}">
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Structs"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
                </Grid>




        </DataTemplate>            

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: It does work here. Can you give all the content of `Window.Resources`?

Comment: Yes but it is really big and i can't put it in the comment

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another resource that doesn't have a `key`? @Yogevnn You can edit your question for that.

Comment: @Yogevnn You can edit your question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `<DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate" DataType="ca:Interface">` is declared before the `ResourceDictionary`. You have to declare it **in** or **after** the `ResourceDictionary`.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
            <!-- 
            Merge in the resource dictionary that is shared between the main window and the overview window.
            -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedVisualTemplates.xaml" />    
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate" DataType="ca:Interface">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

// Other resources
</ResourceDictionary>
```

or

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
            <!-- 
            Merge in the resource dictionary that is shared between the main window and the overview window.
            -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedVisualTemplates.xaml" />    
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       // Other resources
  </ResourceDictionary>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate" DataType="ca:Interface">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: On the same code I'm getting now an exception:
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate'.

Comment: @Yogevnn Did you use `StaticResource` when using a key from a `DataTemplate`? Eg.: `Template="{StaticResource key}"`

Comment: No i didn't:
            <DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate"
                  DataType="ca:Interface">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

Comment: @Yogevnn No, I mean where u **use** the `DataTemplate`. So not in `Windows.Resources`, but onto an UI-element.

Comment: Oh sorry. Here: 
    
                        <ListBox Name="lbInterfaces"  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Interfaces}" ItemTemplate="InterfacesDataTemplate" >         
                            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                        </ListBox>

Comment: @Yogevnn Your `ItemTemplate="InterfacesDataTemplate"` has to be `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InterfacesDataTemplate}"`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That solved my problem! (My WPF skills are really low..)

Comment: @Yogevnn Glad I could help! You have to start somewhere. :)